# Which kind/model of sensor is appropriate for detecting vibration at one end of 1000 m steel block?

Tags: vibration

We have to detect vibration/sound produced at rail track for upcoming train at 1000 m distances . So which sensor is appropriate here? thanks.

Comment: Seem to remember this being asked a few days ago...

Comment: Found it : https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/446431/152903

Comment: That was at electronics stackexchange. There  TimWescott  suggests to move this post to engineering stackexchange.

Comment: Tim also gave you a suggestion - have you checked that out? Transistor also gave you a suggestion, did you check that out? Or did you just jump on the “post on engineering”? If you did check out the two suggestions then updating your question with the results would be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect sound, use a microphone.  If you want to detect vibration, there are a few options, but probably the default option would be a piezoelectric accelerometer.  For both microphones and accelerometers, there are thousands of models available depending on the frequency and amplitude range you care about. Cost will be in the hundreds of US dollars range.

If you can provide more detail about what you need to do, we can give you a better answer.

Comment: If the rails have expansion gaps, will that cause a problem sensing vibration?

Comment: expansion gaps are connected by fish plates. So, there will be no problem sensing vibration.

Comment: I second suggesting piezo-accelerometers. Note that the electronics needed to get the rated performance from the piezo itself are non-trivial, so I suggest getting sensor and electronics from the same Manufacturer. Kistler is one brand name I recall; your mileage may vary.